# Matplotlib: Changing the colour of the line after certain point in index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors

I've been exploring Matplotlib and pandas for abit over a month now and i was wondering if there is any way that i can change the colour of a given graphed line after a certain value of the index had been passed, I couldn't find anything remotely similar within the Matplotlib documentation and would greatly appreciate anyones expertise.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))

num = 0
for i in df['GDP']:
    num +=1
    if num > 263:
        df.plot(color = 'r', ax=ax1)
    else:
        df.plot(color= 'r', ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

I thought something like this would work but to my luck it did not.

note: Im working with GDP figures which is the only column in my data frame if anyone was wondering :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite line by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select column `GDP` where compare index values (`index` has to be increasing monotonic, default):

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(30,2)), columns=['GDP', 'A'])
#print (df)

N = 20
ax = df['GDP'].plot(color='y')
df.loc[df.index >= N, 'GDP'].plot(color='r', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]